# Ninject InSingletonScope() view model isn't assigned to a view at binding

Tags: .net, mvvm, inversion-of-control, ninject

I am assuming that when in NinjectModule I bind

```
Bind<SplashViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
```

an instance of `SplashViewModel` is being kind of a cached in Ninject kernel and each time I call `kernel.Get<SplashViewModel>` I would be getting the very same instance of a view model returned to me. This is what happens, true.

In my `NinjectUIModule` I call:

```
Bind<SplashViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
Bind<SplashWindow>().ToMethod(context => new SplashWindow()
                                                       {
                                                           DataContext = new SplashViewModel()
                                                       });
```

The problem is that a `SplashWindow` gets a different new instance of `SplashViewModel`, not the instance that is cached in Ninject kernel and is returned to all other retrieving parties.

How can I bind view model to a View's DataContext in a Ninject module, and allow it to be returned via kernel.Get  to other code in the application later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your SplashWindow would take the SplashViewModel as a ctor arg, then that initialization would be taken care for you by Ninject. You will not even need to define the SplashWindow binding.

Comment: either this or put the `[Inject]` attribute on the `DataContext` property in SplashWindow.  then just make your SplashWindow binding a normal self binding.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked around the problem by the following binding approach:

```
class NinjectUIModule: NinjectModule
    {
        public override void Load()
        {
            Bind<SplashViewModel>().ToSelf().InSingletonScope();
            Bind<SplashWindow>().ToMethod(context => new SplashWindow()
                                                         {
                                                            DataContext = Kernel.Get<SplashViewModel>()
                                                         });
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if this is the perfect solution though.